# Django prefetch_related ValueError

Tags: django, django-orm

Can't make `prefetch_related` to work.

These are models:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DOCUMENT_TYPE)
    document_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)


class OrderManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OrderManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(document_type=DOCUMENT_ORDER)


class Order(Document):

    objects = OrderManager()

    @property
    def items(self):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(document=self)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class OrderItem(Item):

    objects = OrderItemManager()


class Item(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, related_name='items')
```

Now when call:

```
Order.objects.all().prefetch_related('items')
```

error:

```
ValueError: 'items' does not resolve to an item that supports prefetching - this is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related().
```

`items` is in `related_name`, why i get this error?

`Order` is proxy model.

EDIT:
When do this:

```
Document.objects.all().prefetch_related('items')
```

it works.

Need solution to make it work from `Order` model.

Comment: Does it work if you query from the parent model, Document?

Comment: It does work when i call from `Document`. Any solution to work from `Order`?

Comment: It seems like the problem is in your OrderManager class, could you show the code for that?

Comment: Updated `OrderManager` and `Order` class, can you look now? I have this `items` property, maybe that is problem.

Comment: Try removing the `items` property from the `Order` model.

Comment: I think it works, now i have problem with django rest framework, it wont get data from prefetch_related, but i will look for that.. Thanks